# how can I use the for loop inside the copy task in ant script

Tags: ant

I have a file which is having some variables, I want to copy each line from this to other file except for the lines which has the **type=Password**.

here is the sample file.

```
<Environment xsi:type="amxdata:Environment" name="@AMX_ENVIRONMENT_NAME@">  
    <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="FF_JDBC_USERNAME" type="String" value="@SVAR_ENV_JDBC_USERNAME@" />
    <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="FF_JDBC_PASSWORD" type="Password" value="@SVAR_ENV_JDBC_PASSWORD@" />
        <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="MON_JMS_USERNAME" type="String" value="@MON_EMS_USER@" />
    <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="MON_JMS_PASSWORD" type="Password" value="@MON_EMS_PASSWORD@" />        
    </Environment>
```

### Output file:

```
<Environment xsi:type="amxdata:Environment" name="@AMX_ENVIRONMENT_NAME@">  
    <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="FF_JDBC_USERNAME" type="String" value="@SVAR_ENV_JDBC_USERNAME@" />
        <SVar xsi:type="amxdata_base:SubstitutionVariable" name="MON_JMS_USERNAME" type="String" value="@MON_EMS_USER@" />
</Environment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would accomplish your task.  It reads `in.xml` into property `xml-content` excluding the lines with `type="Password"` and prints the new contents into `out.xml`.

```
<target name="strip-passwords">
  <loadfile property="xml-content" srcFile="in.xml" >
    <filterchain>
      <linecontainsregexp negate="true"> 
        <regexp pattern="\Qtype=&quot;Password&quot;\E"/> 
      </linecontainsregexp>
    </filterchain>
  </loadfile>
  <echo message="${xml-content}" file="out.xml"/>
</target>
```